# awk grep the last 30 days of logs by keyword

Tags: bash, awk, grep

trying to do a precise query of log files (i.e. all the bounces in the last 30 days).

I seam to be missing 2 factors, I don't think stdin will pull zcat info and I think there is also an error passing the variable to awk.

```
home # lastDate=$(date -d "last month" 2>&1 {$1, $2, $3}) | cat /var/log/messages | zcat /var/log/messages-* | awk '$0>=from&&$0<=to' from='{ print date +"%m-%d"}' to=$lastDate '{print to}' | grep -i reject
awk: fatal: cannot open file `{print to}' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

---

where broke:

```
lastDate=$(date -d "last month" 2>&1 {$1, $2, $3})|awk '{print lastDate}'



no error, no output
```

---

date -d "last month"
Fri Jul 26 07:13:40 UTC 2013

Comment: the lastDate command is not ok. Which fields do you require from the date command?

Comment: What do you think this command should be doing? `date -d "last month" 2>&1 {$1, $2, $3}`

Comment: Your command line makes no sense, it's just a random bunch of snippets of pseudo-shell and pseudo-awk code. Tell us what you're trying to do and provide some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use back tics, use parentheses:

```
awk 'tolower($0)~/reject/ && $0~Date' Date=$(date -d'now-30 days' +[%d/%b:%H:%M:%S) /var/log/messages && zcat /var/log/messages-*
```

In your post, you does not use Date, so you get all records regardless what date it is

PS update your post #1, instead of posting new.

EDIT:
If you like a range of date, not use on day, 30 day ago, try this:

```
awk 'tolower($0)~/reject/ && $0>=from && $0<=to' from=$(date -d'now-30 days' +[%d/%b:%H:%M:%S) to==$(date +[%d/%b:%H:%M:%S) /var/log/messages && zcat /var/log/messages-*
```

Comment: and the keyword reject isn't found without adding |grep reject to the end

Comment: [ "Aug 26" not found ]  when I run your EDIT: script